# как без формы с инпут файл отправит файл?

Tags: php, jquery

```
<label class="label btn" for="file"> Загрузить<input enctype="multipart/form-data" class="answer5 file" name="answer5" id="file" type="file" placeholder="Загрузить" value="Загрузить"></label>
```

JS

```
var file;


$(".fail").onchange(function(){
    file = $('.file')[0].files[0];

    )


    function endtest() {
        const formData = new FormData;
        formData.append("ebody", `<h3>Телефон:&nbsp;${tel}</h3><h3>Вопрос0:&nbsp;${answer1}</h3><h3>Вопрос1:&nbsp;${answer2}</h3><h3>Вопрос2:&nbsp;${answer3}</h3><h3>Вопрос3:&nbsp;${answer4}</h3><h3>Вопрос4:&nbsp;${answer5}</h3><h3>Вопрос6:&nbsp;${answer6}</h3>`);
        formData.append("file", file);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST"
            , url: "test.php"
            , data: formData
            , processData: false
            , cache: false
            , contentType: false
            , dataType: "json"
        }).done(function () {
            $("#message-send-ok").addClass("active");
        }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        });
    }
```

PHP

```
<?php 

    $from = "<Фаворит>";


    if (isset($_POST['ebody'])) {$ebody = $_POST['ebody'];} 



    $mailTo ="g@mail.ru";

    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
     // от кого
    $subject = "Прошел тест"; // тема письма

    $message = $ebody;  // текст письма
    $r = sendMailAttachment($mailTo, $from, $subject, $message, $file); // отправка письма c вложением
    echo ($r)?'':'';


    function sendMailAttachment($mailTo, $from, $subject, $message, $file = false){
        $separator = "---"; // разделитель в письме
        // Заголовки для письма
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: $from\nReply-To: $from\n"; // задаем от кого письмо
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$separator\""; // в заголовке указываем разделитель
        // если письмо с вложением
        if($file){
            $bodyMail = "--$separator\n"; // начало тела письма, выводим разделитель
            $bodyMail .= "Content-type:text/html; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email"; // кодировка письма
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable"; // задаем конвертацию письма
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n\n"; // задаем название файла
            $bodyMail .= $message."\n"; // добавляем текст письма
            $bodyMail .= "--$separator\n";
            $fileRead = fopen($file, "r"); // открываем файл
            $contentFile = fread($fileRead, filesize($file)); // считываем его до конца
            fclose($fileRead); // закрываем файл
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n"; 
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"; // кодировка файла
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n\n";
            $bodyMail .= chunk_split(base64_encode($contentFile))."\n"; // кодируем и прикрепляем файл
            $bodyMail .= "--".$separator ."--\n";
        // письмо без вложения
        }else{
            $bodyMail = $message;
        }
        $result = mail($mailTo, $subject, $bodyMail, $headers); // отправка письма
        return $result;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        formData.append("file", $('.file')[0].files[0]);
```

`var file` - локальная переменная внутри обработчика `change`, ее не видно внутри функции `endtest`.

Comment: обработчик при отправлении на меил отсылает файл с названием,но весом 0

Comment: @ЭнрикоТакатти покажите Ваш html

Comment: <label class="label btn" for="file"> Загрузить<input enctype="multipart/form-data" class="answer5 file" name="answer5" id="file" type="file" placeholder="Загрузить" value="Загрузить"></label>